# C++ How to make a non void function return nothing for if else statements?

Tags: c++

So my problem goes like this:

```
string something (string something){
    string letter;
    cout << "press a";
    cin >> letter;
    if (letter==a){
        return a;
    }
    else
    cout << "wrong letter";
    //what should I put here if I don't want it to return any value?
}
```

Any alternatives would also be welcome

Comment: See [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Or throw an exception.

Comment: I suppose you mean `'a'` not `a`

Comment: To add to the collection of possible approaches: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding -- return a tuple string+bool where the bool tells you whether the string is valid.

Comment: There are too many possibilities.   Why have you decided that your function must return `void` and why (at the same time) do you need to return something to the caller if the user enters an invalid string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this would be a `std::optional<std::string>`

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::string> dingas(std::string something)
{
    string letter;
    cout << "press a";
    cin >> letter;
    if (letter==something){
        return "a";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "wrong letter";
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Comment: `if (letter==a){` is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a single character you could use a `char`. However, if the function is declared to return a `std::string` but you do not want to return a `std::string` you have several options:

- return an empty `std::string`
- change signature to `bool something(std::string& out)` such that the return value signals sucess and when it is `true` the result is written to `out`.
- change the return type to `std::optional<std::string>`. A `std::optional<std::string>` either contains a `std::string` or not.
- throw an exception instead of `return`

Which one you pick is up to you. Exceptions should be used for exceptional cases, so you need to decide if not returning is "normal" or exceptional. It will require the caller to handle the exception. `bool something(std::string&)` is similarly inconvenient for the caller, because they need to check the return value and provide the string to be used. Usually a sentinal value (ie giving special meaning to the empty string) can cause problems, because one day you might confuse the sentinal with a proper return value. Though, as the function either returns a string with a single character or not, this isnt a big issue. I'd prefer the `std::optional`, but thats just my biased opinion.

Comment: A bit too complicated for me to understand but I'll do my research.

Comment: @imessedup which part do you not understand? In other answers there are examples for using an exception and for using `std::optional`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the exception mechanism for this: this carries the advantage that you can keep a reasonable return type, and you can also delegate handling of the exception to the caller of the function.

First, write

```
struct WrongLetterException : public std::exception{};
```

Then change the function to

```
std::string something (std::string something/*ToDo - is this correct?*/){
    std::string letter;
    std::cout << "press a";
    std::cin >> letter;
    if (letter == "a"/*note the change here*/){
        return a;
    }
    throw WrongLetterException();
}
```

In the caller to the function, you then `catch (const WrongLetterException& ex)` and deal with it as you see fit.